# SharePoint authentication via a proxy server

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, proxy

A client has trouble logging into our webpart (SP 2007).  Apparently, his internet connection is via a proxy server.  He has no problem logging in to our main website.  Authentication from both the webpart and the website is through the same API.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think  the proxy server is the prob. 
Browser authentication over proxy is not supported when using NTLM.

Sharepoint uses NTLM or Kerberos authentication.